# Ubuntu 15.04 nvidia 346.59 external monitor display - windows stretched; click offset is off

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, nvidia-optimus, 15.04

I have used the same hardware setup with Ubuntu 14 and didn't have any problems with the nvidia driver (not sure which one I used back then).

Seems to work fine in "only external monitor" "only built-in display" or "screen mirroring" mode. But when it comes to extending desktop on multiple displays, windows look extremely stretched horizontally and click offset if off by a lot.

Tried the following:
- X.org driver is O.K but slow and flickers on the external monitor
- Cycling through display modes with no avail
- Couldn't find any BIOS setting for nvidia optimus to try turning it off

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem for months and even downgraded to 14.04.2 to see if that would help with Nvidia 331-updates. After a bit of research I found a bug on launchpad and the [fix] (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1382462/comments/35) suggested here sorted it for me at last (Asus N56VM with Nvidia 630M/Intel). Phew!

> [Install] CompizConfig Settings Manager, go to "General Options", then
>   "Display Settings" and do the following:
>
> - Uncheck "Detect Outputs"
> - In the Outputs array, set the resolutions of each of your screens. The numbers after the resolution "1920x1080+0+0" are the offset. It's
>     important to add this offset according to your needs. I have two full
>     HD screens, so I added the following configuration: 1920x1080+0+0
>     1920x1080+1920+0
>
> The second output has an offset of 1920, because it is on the right
>   side of the first output, which has a width of 1920.